# The proper way to invalidate and flush Vulkan memory

Tags: vulkan, memory-alignment

When flushing and invalidating non-coherent memory in Vulkan you need to do it to ranges with a starting offset and size both aligned to an alignment called 'nonCoherentAtomSize', which on my physical device is 128 bytes. To do this you would round DOWN the starting offset and round UP the size to this alignment (128 bytes). The issue I can see is that types have a less strict (smaller) alignment, and this rounding up and down can spill the range outside the memory of the allocation. So:

```
// CREATE A BUFFER WITH SIZE 17
VkMemoryRequirements memRequirements;
vkGetBufferMemoryRequirements(logicalDevice, vk_buffer, &memRequirements);

memRequirements.size; // == 20
memRequirements.alignment; // == 4
// ON MY SETUP
```

Let's just say I allocate 20 bytes of memory and I this buffer at the beginning, (0), and I want to flush this range, I would flush offset 0 with size 20 (but this needs to rounded up to 128 (nonCoherentAtomSize), which is bigger than the buffer. This isn't right, right? Likewise, is the memory returned from vkAllocateMemory guaranteed to be aligned to at least the nonCoherentAtomSize? If not the memory might begin only at a 16-byte alignment, and if I round down then I'm flushing a range before the memory, right?

Edit: Sorry, it's impossible in the case of rounding down, because the argument to flush and invalidate is an offset, anything rounded down to its alignment cannot be less than 0. But in the case of rounding up it's still a problem I can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is never a reason to map a range of an allocation which is not aligned to `nonCoherentAtomSize`. If you do this, then you will find that you will be unable to properly flush or invalidate part of that range.

Indeed, there is no reason to ever map only *part* of an allocation you intend to map. Just map the whole thing, immediately after allocating it. At which point, you can use `VK_WHOLE_SIZE` to specify a size if the `nonCoherentAtomSize` aligned `size` exceeds the allocation range.

Comment: If the allocation size is 146 then I'd round up the flush range size to 256 and I'd flush outside the memory allocation, that's my point. Is the typical way to round up and use the max of the the rounding up figure and the allocation size?

Comment: @Zebrafish: "*If the allocation size is 146 then I'd round up the flush range size to 256*" And then you would realize that the rounded size is outside of the memory allocation, so you would use `VK_WHOLE_SIZE`, like I said.